# Android FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two replaces (action A and action B) while my work flow, which I commit to the `FragmentManager`.

If action A is executed the action B is executed as well, but if action B is executed first, the action A can't be executed, because the view id isn't visible in the layout.

How can I cancel the execution of action A, if action B is executed first or how can I set the transaction order/priority? I don't know if action B should be executed, while adding action A to the `FragmentManager`.

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: I didn't think this help. I send two intents, which create this replace. I try to extract it to a simple example later.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using the child fragment manager of the fragments since it seems that transaction B can remove the view that the fragments from transaction A get added to

Comment: @FunkTheMonk You're correct. B changes a bigger fragment. Do you have any examples for the ChildFragmentManager, because I don't know it.

Comment: It's not a problem of the `FragmentManager`. I sent local intents and the receiver started the fragment transaction. After setting this to normal methods, my problem is no more existing.